# How to have apache serve nextcloud index when pointing directly to the server url?

Tags: apache2, owncloud-server, nextcloud

[image]
I seem to have made some mistake in trying to [fix an issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845197/how-to-correctly-install-cryptography-in-python-2-7-x-ubuntu-14-04) with letsencrypt, and now when I enter the URL for the server, I get a list of the directories as opposed to the nextcloud `index.php` (which is what it was serving by default before).

I don't know of any change that I could have made along the way that should cause this, but it's happening anyway. I guess it is a chance to learn.

How can I have the server go straight to url.etc/owncloud as opposed to showing a pair of folders?

P.S. I'm not an apache expert but I did look this up before asking and nothing jumped out at me.
P.S. 2 I couldn't think of a better title - feel free to edit (I'm tired, to be honest).

Comment: So you want `foo.xyz/` to go to `foo.xyz/owncloud`?

Comment: Yeah, basically. Before I fiddled around (just with a2dissite and a2ensite and a2dismod and a2enmod, and renaming conf files (before setting them back to normal), when you go to foo.xyz, it would load the nextcloud/owncloud login screen. Now, it loads what you see in the screenshot.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/q/58762/229499, perhaps. Or just change the `DocumentRoot` to point to `/var/www/owncloud` if you just want `foo.xyz` to serve Owncloud directly.

Comment: I found the issue. I had figured, like you suggested, that somehow the document root was changed, though I didn't change it myself. It turns out it was another site that somehow got enabled accidentally (possibly when I ran software upgrades a few days ago). **Thanks for your assistance!** It pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. The problem is that a non-default site was accidentally enabled (how, I don't know, as I never manually enabled it), that site being an instance of collabora office online (which has yet to actually... work).

- To find out which sites were enabled, I had to run: `apache2ctl -S`
- Then, I had to disable the offender: `a2dissite office`.
- Then restart the server: `service apache2 restart`.

Note: this is a 14.04 server, the last command would be `systemctl restart apache2` on 16.04 and up.

*Many thanks to [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) for pointing me in the right direction.*